# Problem when running elastic search on windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch

when i am running elastic search on windows 10 , i can not open elastic portal in the local host and i got this message :

> {   "name" : "ISBUS-PC02",   "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
> "cluster_uuid" : "FE38HTACR2evmiVFD7ciag",   "version" : {
> "number" : "8.6.0",
> "build_flavor" : "default",
> "build_type" : "zip",
> "build_hash" : "f67ef2df40237445caa70e2fef79471cc608d70d",
> "build_date" : "2023-01-04T09:35:21.782467981Z",
> "build_snapshot" : false,
> "lucene_version" : "9.4.2",
> "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
> "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"   },   "tagline" : "You Know, for Search" }

nothing, because this is the last issue i stucked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JSON you provided means Elasticsearch is up and running perfectly fine. You can note in the JSON response, Elasticsearch cluster name, version, build type and other information is also provided.

```
{
    "name": "ISBUS-PC02",
    "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
    "cluster_uuid": "FE38HTACR2evmiVFD7ciag",
    "version":
    {
        "number": "8.6.0",
        "build_flavor": "default",
        "build_type": "zip",
        "build_hash": "f67ef2df40237445caa70e2fef79471cc608d70d",
        "build_date": "2023-01-04T09:35:21.782467981Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "9.4.2",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "7.17.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "7.0.0"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

**You don't have to worry**, your Elasticsearch cluster is up and running and you can execute other requests.

Comment: Hi amit, thank you for ur response,, but i main i can not navigate in elastic main portal on local host  neither private ip. Only see this JSON response

Comment: @hasanmarah there is no UI for Elasticsearch, if you want UI than you need to use kibana

Comment: @hasanmarah but you can still interact it with APIs

Comment: Hmm, i got ur point, thank you amit